# Can you save fingerprint from fingerprint sensor usually found in laptops and smartphone?

Tags: windows-10, fingerprint

Is it possible to save a jpg of fingerprint, right now fingerprint sensors found in laptops and mobiles are used to unlock them.

Comment: Biometric fingerprint sensors don’t work based of a direct image of your fingerprint.  How and what happens differ from OS to OS.

Comment: Computers never store passwords. You store a one way mathematical transformation called a hash. When you enter a password it is hashed and compared to the stored hash. When you read in the paper that 1 million passwords have been stolen be aware it is roughly 2 million years to crack them all (two years per password).

Comment: i dont think i said to extract stored data and reproduce a finger print. Instead. get data from the sensor, raw data and print it.

Answer (score 5):

> You will not be able to see your fingerprint since the fingerprint
>   that you add will be stored only in the backend. It is used to compare
>   with the stored fingerprint when you try to unlock with fingerprint.
>
> And moreover fingerprint will not be stored as image format. During
>   unlocking your fingerprint image sent for extraction in the IC chip.
>
> The extraction takes place by image processing, and extracted details
>   are stored as templates.
>
> So the template of your default fingerprint is compared with the
>   fingerprint that you give during unlocking. If matched, your screen is
>   unlocked.
>
> Templates are not even part of the OS, so its impossible to retrieve
>   the fingerprint image. Templates will be stored only in ICs.

So basically you can't export your fingerprint as picture. In high-end devices, fingerprint data will be encrypted and can't be exported.

Source: [Quora.com](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-display-your-fingerprint-on-a-fingerprint-scanner-smartphone)

Comment: To add, patterns are almost always the ones stored even in an insecure system as otherwise matching fingerprints when you have ever-so-slightly dirty fingers, dirty sensor, or even aligning it a different angle will not produce a match. While insecure system's you could extract the pattern, it wouldn't be useful to you as it wouldn't be in the image format. Some fingerprint scanners (NOT like smartphone or laptop ones) work *optically* and can produce a picture of the print if requested in software.

Comment: I didn't say to extract finger prints from stored and encrypted data / templates. But instead directly from the sensors.

Comment: In PC, tablet or smartphone, fingerprint sensor is just work as a scanner. The data won't be stored in there.

Comment: So can you use the scanner to get the fingerprint, it doesn't matter if it gets stored or not?